# Creating users with Unicode characters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, unicode

I'm tasked with creating users for an organization on a bunch of new Windows Server 2012 machines, and some of these users have names that contain characters that I can't seem to get PowerShell to get along with. My code so far is this:

```
$users = "Lars", "Brian", "Andreas"
$descriptions = "Lars Poulsen", "Brian Hansen", "Andreas Jørgensen"
$d = 0
Foreach($u in $users) {
  echo $descriptions[$d]
  $d++
}
```

Using the above code, one will get the effect, but the users will have non-corresponding names to the names in the collection.

I tried with the following at the top of the script:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Doing so only returned an error from PowerShell, stating that "A device attached to the system is not functioning."

Comment: What did you expect from your code? And how actual results different from that? I see nothing wrong about it.

Comment: I was expecting it to return "Andreas Jørgensen" not "Andreas JÃ¸rgensen".

Comment: I copy paste your code to PowerShell console and get `Andreas Jørgensen` in the results. How did you execute your code?

Comment: Trying to run it from a file, to have it portable to all the servers.

Comment: What encoding you use for file? Does it have BOM?

Comment: Turned out that was the mistake. Notepad++ had saved it  without BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was simply Notepad++ saving the file as UTF-8 without BOM. Check your encodings, people.